# Отправка ключей шифрования по сети в JAVA

Tags: java, сокет, криптография, null, key

У меня проблема с передачей PublicKey по сети (локальной, всемирной). При попытке передать ключ, он не передаётся и получается null.
Вот код:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static PublicKey publicKey;
    public static PrivateKey privateKey;
    public static PublicKey serverKey;
    public static Cipher cipher;

    public static Socket socketC;
    public static Socket socketS;
    public static ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public static ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
    public static ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;

    public static class Server implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
                socketS = serverSocket.accept();
                objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socketS.getInputStream());

                serverKey = (PublicKey) objectInputStream.readObject();
                objectInputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception ignore){}
        }
    }

    public static class Client {
        public Client(){
            try {
                socketC = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4444);
                objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socketC.getOutputStream());

                objectOutputStream.writeObject(publicKey);
                objectOutputStream.flush();
                objectOutputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception ignore){}
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
            publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
            privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

            new Thread(new Server()).start();
            new Client();


            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(publicKey.getEncoded()));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(serverKey.getEncoded()));

            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("qwerty");

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
            byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal("qwerty".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
            System.out.println(new String(cipher.doFinal(bytes)));

            System.out.println();

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, serverKey);
            byte[] bytes1 = cipher.doFinal("qwerty".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
            System.out.println(new String(cipher.doFinal(bytes1)));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

И выдаётся ошибка java.lang.NullPointerException в строчке          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(serverKey.getEncoded()));

Как это можно решить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сервер ждёт пока к его сокету кто-нибудь подключится. После того, как клиент установил соединение, сервер ждёт данные для чтения. Клиент их записал и пошёл дальше. Сервер в свою очередь начинает их читать, НО клиент исполняется в главном потоке => продолжает выполняться метод main. Отсюда и NullPointer, т.к. сервер ещё не успел прочитать.

Решается задержкой после вызова клиента, типа `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100)`